# Meteor crash when running or deploy

Tags: meteor, crash

When i run meteor command

Im getting a crash
I have done some changes, in the 
accounts-ui packange and accounts-ui-unstyled, Already tryed to fix it but fail.Shoud i reinstall Meteor?

Here is the erorr:

```
/home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: couldn't read entire resource
    at /home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isopack.js:693:19
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isopack.js:677:9
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at _.extend._loadUnibuildsFromPath (/home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isopack.js:648:7)
    at _.extend.initFromPath (/home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/isopack.js:512:17)
    at _.extend.loadPackageAtPath (/home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-cache.js:138:12)
    at _.extend.getPackage (/home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-loader.js:66:38)
    at Object.compiler.eachUsedUnibuild (/home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/compiler.js:85:37)
    at compileUnibuild (/home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/compiler.js:337:14)
    at /home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/compiler.js:1060:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at Object.compiler.compile (/home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/compiler.js:1059:5)
    at /home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:1973:26
    at /home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:254:13
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:247:29
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:245:18
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:236:23
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at Object.capture (/home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:235:19)
    at Object.exports.bundle (/home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:1895:31)
    at Object.bundleAndDeploy (/home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/deploy.js:403:32)
    at main.registerCommand.name [as func] (/home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/commands.js:1038:27)
    at /home/kristian/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/main.js:1255:23
```

Comment: What happens when you reinstall meteor?

Comment: I haven't reinstalled yet